# Sliding glass door

Tags: doors

I want to leave the fixed side of my sliding glass door and install an exterior door on the moveable side, can this be done if so what would I need to do.

Comment: Install a double French door

Comment: Double French door one side fixed I should say they cost less

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can give a detailed answer.

Comment: I have a 36" exterior door with casing, was hoping to use it instead of having to buy another door 9 French Door) was told the fixed side of the sliding glass door can stay and the exterior door I have can be installed where the sliding side is located, just not sure how to do it and want to make sure who ever I call knows what they are talking about. So I need to know how it's done.